# Spring cannot import application-context from test package of different module

Tags: spring, testing, import, applicationcontext

I have a Java application that consists of two modules, ModuleA and ModuleB.

In ModuleB's test context, applicationContextB-test.xml (see below), I try to import beans from the test context of ModuleA, applicationContextA-test.xml, like this:

```
<import resource="classpath*:applicationContextA-test.xml"/>
```

The beans in applicationContextA-test.xml can't be found, which results in exceptions when I run my unit tests in ModuleB:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire field

- Intellij already indicates that applicationContextA-test.xml can't be found.
- Intellij also shows that applicationContextA.xml CAN be found.
- In the pom.xml of module B there is a dependency defined on ModuleA.

Do you know why I am able to reference ModuleA's normal applicationContext, but not ModuleA's test application context?

---

```
/ModuleA
    /src/main/resources/
         - applicationContextA.xml
    /src/test/resources/
        - applicationContextA-test.xml

pom.xml
```

---

```
/ModuleB
    /src/main/resources/
         - applicationContextB.xml
    /src/test/resources/
        - applicationContextB-test.xml
pom.xml
```

Comment: test sources and resources are only locally available, they aren't part of the generated jar file and as such not available to other projects. This restriction also applies to projects in the same workspace everything under test is only visible to the module it is defined in.

Comment: Thanks. That clears things up. For now I will copy A's test config to ModuleB. I would like to know how I can avoid copying app configs when using multiple submodules though. How about putting the test context in the normal source folder of ModuleA, so that it can be referenced from other modules for test purposes, and excluding it from the build with Maven?

Comment: Just create a separate submodule in maven (e.g. test-infrastrucrure), put the resources there and refer to that module as test dependencies in your other modules. And BTW, your resources should be in `src/main/resources`, not `src/main/java/resources`.

Comment: Sounds like a plan. Thanks. The resources folder is in the right place in my project. I edited my initial post to reflect that.